# Why properties of an XMLHttpRequest object are only printable through console.log()?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, xmlhttprequest, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(obj));
console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(obj))
console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log("console.log:"); console.log(obj)
```

output:

> Object.keys(): []
>   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(): []
>   Object.entries(): []
>   JSON.stringify(): {}
>   console.log:
>   XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 0, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}

How can I create such an object in javascript, whose properties are only printed using `console.log(obj)`, but not returned by **any** of the above functions?

I have already tried to create objects using `constructor function`, `object.create()` (with `enumerable:false`),  `Object.assign()`, using `getters`, instatiating from a class, instatiating from an extended class e.t.c

Comment: Hii @Marinos An please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/atsw0dx1/4/) fiddle. Is this what you want is ?

Comment: Hi @JaydeepMor. No.

Comment: The closest you'll get is with inherited getters, i.e. `Object.create({get test() { return 1; }})`. But no, XHR is a host object and the console can do with it whatever it wants.

Comment: @Bergi indeed the host object is receving a special treatment from the browsers, however such treatment can be reproduced using chrome object custom formatters

Comment: After a long time [I also came up with a close answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62173620/1555615)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create such an object in javascript, whose properties are only printed using console.log(obj), but not returned by any of the above functions?

One **close solution** I have found is the one **below**. This will print properties with `console.log(obj)`. However obj is a Proxy.

On chrome console the result is the same as `XMLHttpRequest` output (with class being `Proxy`). On firefox console it a representation of the `Proxy` class, so it is not exactly the same.

```js
    const obj = new Proxy({prop1:"value1", prop2: "value2"}, {ownKeys: _=>[]});

    console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(obj));
    console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
    console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(obj))
    console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(obj))
    console.log(obj)
```

result:

> Object.keys(): []
>   Object.getOwnPropertyNames(): []
>   Object.entries(): []
>   JSON.stringify(): {}
>   console.log:
>   Proxy {prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2"}

and `console.log(obj.prop1) / obj.prop1="newValue"` still works.

Comment: Interesting. This is probably the closest to what the xhr host object does.

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the WhatWG `console.log` [specification](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer):

> How the implementation prints args is up to the implementation, but implementations should separate the objects by a space or something similar, as that has become a developer expectation.

The spec leaves the output format very vague and it's up to the implementation to decide what to print.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the new data type called Symbol to create the keys for an JavaScript object.

Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

I have attached an sample code and you can see the output in console.

```js
let nameSymbol = Symbol('name');
function Person (name) {
 this[nameSymbol] = name;
}

Person.prototype.toString = function toPersonString() {
 var symArr = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(this);
 for (let sym of symArr) {
  this[sym.description] = this[sym];
  delete this[sym];
 }
 return this;
}

const dummyObject = new Person('random value');

console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(dummyObject)); // []
console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dummyObject)) // []
console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(dummyObject)) // []
console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(dummyObject)) // {}

console.log("console.log:", dummyObject.toString()); //  {name: "random value"}
```

Comment: I don't think we have any direct way to convert properties from symbol to string, but we can overload the toString method and return the property names again.

Comment: Can you update the code with what you've proposed. If `console.log()` prints the object properties as in case of `XMLHttpRequest` I guess the answer will worth the bounty.

Comment: I have updated the code with a new approach. Now you just need to call toString method(or any method) and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for the update but the `toString()` needs to be explicitly called in this solution. Plus after calling it the `Object.keys(dummyObject)` and the rest of the functions start printing the property.

Comment: It's not same as `XHR`. The `XHR` instance does not have symbols. In this code, if one has to access the name property, it'll be like `dummyObject1.toString().name` and `dummyObject1.name` would give `undefined`.

Comment: @MarinosAn I tried and checked but not able to resolve. Seems like some internal implementation of XMLHttpRequest to me, even NodeList objects behaves the same way. Will let you know if find anything.

Comment: This is not related to symbols or regular keys, this is more about instance properties against inherited properties.

Answer (score 3):

All the properties on an XMLHttpRequest instance are inherited properties, what i mean by that is that they don't exist on the instance itself but rather on its prototype chain.

This explains why

```
const x = new XMLHttpRequest()
// all these methods consider only instance properties (owned properties) and thats why they return empty results
console.log(Object.keys(x)) // []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)) // []
console.log(Object.entries(x)) // []
console.log(JSON.stringify(x)) // {}


// however if you try this you will get the results you want

console.log(Object.keys(x.__proto__)) // will not return symbol keys
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(x.__proto__)) // will return descriptiors of every property whether its symbol or not

// you can see these results also by logging the xmlRequest, and looking at its __proto__ property in the console

// i will be calling the XMLHttpRequest instance for short as xmlRequest
```

You can create such an object simply like this

```
class A {}
A.prototype.someProperty = 10
const a = new A()
// again if you try these you will get results like the XMLHttpRequest instance
console.log(Object.keys(a)) // []
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)) // []
console.log(Object.entries(a)) // []
console.log(JSON.stringify(a)) // {}
```

however when you try to `console.log(a)` you won't see the `someProperty` like you do with the xmlRequest instance, and this is expected, since it is an inherited property. The reason that you see these properties when you log the xmlRequest is that this object is recieving special treatment.

Luckily you can recreate such a special treatment using [chrome custom object formatters](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FTascZXT9cxfetuPRT2eXPQKXui4nWFivUnS_335T3U/preview#heading=h.xuvxhsd2bp05), for this to work you have to enable custom formatters from chrome developer tools settings

```
window.devtoolsFormatters = [{
    header: function(obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof A)){
         return null;
        }
        // to get the exact results like the xmlRequest, you need to remove quotes from the object keys in the json string, can be done with a regex
        return ["div",{}, JSON.stringify(obj.__proto__)]
    },
    hasBody: function(){
        return false;
    }
}]

class A {}
A.prototype.someProperty = 10

console.log(new A()) // {"someProperty":10}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer: I have pasted your code to a snippet, but when executing, it does not print `{"someProperty":10}`

Comment: @MarinosAn did u enable chrome custom formatters from the settings in chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 0):

**Object.keys**: Only gives object's own enumerable property.

**Object.getOwnPropertyNames**: gives enumerable and non-enumerable properties found directly in a given object.

**Object.entries**: give object's own enumerable string-keyed property pairs.

**JSON.stringify**: Only considers objects enumerable properties.

---

#### Creating your own such object

You can use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which will create a new object, using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created object.

```js
obj1 = {
  key1: 'some key'
};

var obj = Object.create(obj1);


console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(obj));
console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(obj))
console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log("console.log:"); console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Try copy/pasting the code in the console of chrome and firefox. `console.log` does not print anything, in contrast to `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: I'm just guessing it's the browser which is doing some extra work to when it prints build-in objects. Like Arrays are Objects too but are printed differently.

Answer (score 0):

It's because prototyping works in Javascript, this is the real reason.

When you create an Object Instance from a prototype, the properties inside `__proto__` will not be shown (not enumerable properties)

For example, try:

```js
function MyXMLHttpRequest(){};
MyXMLHttpRequest.prototype.name = "Edward"
var obj = new MyXMLHttpRequest();

console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(obj));
console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(obj))
console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log("console.log:"); console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.name)
```

You will see:

[image: console prints]

Comment: The code provided does not reproduce the output on my example in which `console. log()` prints a non-empty object.

Comment: Because i wasnt added the own properties.

Answer (score 0):

> Why properties of an XMLHttpRequest object are only printable through console.log()?

That's not true

```js
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
for(var key in obj) console.log(key);
```

Answer on the question from the description

> How can I create such an object in javascript, whose properties are only printed using

```js
  var obj = Object.create({ foo: "foo", constructor: function() {} });
```

If you want to hide property from `for in` you should set `enumerable` attribute to `false` for desired property:

```js
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  value: 42,
  enumerable: false
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer: It is still printed by `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most practical way .It would help you

```
class User {
  //this is a private field
  #name
  get Name() {
    return this.#name
  }
  set Name(val) {
    this.#name = val
  }
}

var obj = new User()
obj.Name = 'test'

console.log('Object.keys():', Object.keys(obj))
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames():', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log('Object.entries():', Object.entries(obj))
console.log('JSON.stringify():', JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log('console.log:')
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.Name)
```

this is its compiled code

```
function _classPrivateFieldSet(receiver, privateMap, value) {
  var descriptor = privateMap.get(receiver)
  if (!descriptor) {
    throw new TypeError('attempted to set private field on non-instance')
  }
  if (descriptor.set) {
    descriptor.set.call(receiver, value)
  } else {
    if (!descriptor.writable) {
      throw new TypeError('attempted to set read only private field')
    }
    descriptor.value = value
  }
  return value
}
function _classPrivateFieldGet(receiver, privateMap) {
  var descriptor = privateMap.get(receiver)
  if (!descriptor) {
    throw new TypeError('attempted to get private field on non-instance')
  }
  if (descriptor.get) {
    return descriptor.get.call(receiver)
  }
  return descriptor.value
} // Try edit message
class User {
  constructor() {
    _name.set(this, { writable: true, value: void 0 })
  }
  get Name() {
    return _classPrivateFieldGet(this, _name)
  }
  set Name(val) {
    _classPrivateFieldSet(this, _name, val)
  }
}
var _name = new WeakMap()
var obj = new User()
obj.Name = 'test'
console.log('Object.keys():', Object.keys(obj))
console.log('Object.getOwnPropertyNames():', Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj))
console.log('Object.entries():', Object.entries(obj))
console.log('JSON.stringify():', JSON.stringify(obj))
console.log('console.log:')
console.log(obj)
console.log(obj.Name)
```

this the result of the compiled version on chromium
[image]

Comment: Than you for the answer. I can still see though the name property on the console. The question states that every console log should print no properties apart from `console.log(obj)` as it happens with `XMLHttpRequest` object

Comment: sorry, I fixed it . I build a js6 class with private field. you can see also js5 format which is es6 compiled result

Comment: But now `console.log(obj)` does not print anything.

Comment: could you please tell me what browser you use to test?

Comment: Chromium. FYI: I execute up to `console.log(obj)`

Comment: try the compiled one ,is results the same?

Comment: The compiled code was the one I used. Tested on firefox also. Last line is:  `console.log: 
 Object {  }` which does not contain the property. I do not execute `console.log(obj.Name)` because it is out of the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
var obj = Object.create({
    get name(){
        return 'I go only to console.log()';
    }
});
console.log("Object.keys():",Object.keys(obj));
console.log("Object.getOwnPropertyNames():",Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
console.log("Object.entries():",Object.entries(obj));
console.log("JSON.stringify():",JSON.stringify(obj));

console.log("console.log:", obj);
```

Comment: Which browser and version did you try this on? On my chrome and firefox I get `console.log: {}` at the end.

Comment: I tried on chrome, also did you expand the last object? Since this is a get property chrome does not print it automatically, you can expand the object and invoke the property getter.

Comment: I know, but with `XMLHttpRequest` instance you don't need to do this, and that's  what the question is about.

Comment: I tried in edge and it does show the value by default. As other answers have also mentioned, this can be a browser specific implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: '123'
});
```

Specifically, `enumerable` thingie hides the property.

For more info see this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

**UPDATE:**

The following approach (improved version of the above) seems to hide properties from all mentioned checks, though it is a little bit verbose:

```
var proto = {};
Object.defineProperty(proto, "key", {
    get: function () { return 123; }
});

var obj = Object.create(proto);

console.log(obj); // {}
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)); // []
console.log(obj.key); // 123
```

Comment: In this case `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` returns non-empty array, with the properties

Comment: In the updated case, `console.log()` also does not print the object properties. While in my example, `console.log()` prints the object properties.